# python entrada de vetor

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho alguns valores de input de uma matriz que terá a entrada da seguinta forma:

1 2 3 4

2 3 4 0

então estou tentando pegar a primeira linha de m+n elementos pra transformar tudo em float, mas não está funcionando.

```
aux = [0]*(m+n)

for i in range(m):
    aux = input()
    print(aux)
    aux = aux.split( )
    print(aux)
    map(float, aux)    

print(aux[1])
```

Comment: Não ficou muito claro o que precisa fazer. Tem como tentar explicar melhor?

Comment: Eu tenho que fazer um simplex e eu terei várias entradas e uma a matriz A, essa matriz teria um tanto n de colunas e m de linhas. a entrada será `1 2 3 4`, por exemplo. Eu preciso transformar isso pra float. Me parece que quando entra com uma linha assim no input() pega como se fosse uma string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema. Mas percebi que o meu problema era pra receber a resposta do `map`

```
m = int(input())
n = int(input())

A = []
for i in range(m):
    A.append( [0] *(m+n))

list = [0]*(n)
new_list = []
List_copy = [0]*(m*n)

for i in range(m):
    lista = input()
    #print(lista)
    lista = lista.split(' ')

    for item in lista:
        new_list.append(float(item))
        #print(new_list)

numpyList = np.asarray(new_list)
A = np.reshape(numpyList, (m,n))
print(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, acho que compreendi o que precisa, então irei focar realmente no problema: um laço de repetição que leia `m` linhas, no formato `a b c d ...`, separe essa linha em valores e converte-os para *float*, mantendo tais valores em uma lista. Para tal, fazemos:

```
m = int(input("Quantas linhas? "))
n = int(input("Quantas colunas? "))

for i in range(m):
    while True:
        row = input()
        values = row.split(' ')

        if len(values) == n:
            break

    values = list(map(float, values))

    print(values)
```

O `for` é para garantir que serão lidos as `m` linhas. O `while` garante que a entrada sempre lerá o número de colunas esperado, evitando assim que o usuário entre com um valor diferente - se a matriz possui 3 colunas, a entrada `1 2` será inválida. Lido a entrada, separamos os valores com `split` nos espaços em branco e convertemos para *float* com a função `map`.

Ou seja, o seu código estava no caminho certo, mas deve ter se enrolado com os retornos da função, lembrando de atribuir o retorno a uma variável. Vale lembrar que o retorno de `map` é um gerador, por isso utilizei `list` para convertê-lo para uma lista.